# IO monad and ordering

Tags: haskell, io, monads, side-effects, io-monad

I am playing with IO monad and learning to harness side effects in Haskell and it seems like I got it wrong.

Consider the following code:

```
main = do
    putStr "test"
    getLine
    return ()
```

My understanding here is that `do` "glues" three IO monads into one. My assumption is that they will be executed in sequence, i.e. "test" will be printed first, then line read, and then dummy `return ()` will produce `()`

However, when I run compiled app it always waits for line to be read **before** printing "test".

Reordering `putStr`/`getLine` does nothig. "Unwrapping" value from IO monad, like this:

```
main = do
    _ <- putStr "test"
    _ <- getLine
    return ()
```

... does not change the result either.

What am I missing here? How to enforce order on IO actions?

Comment: This is probably due to the default line buffering for Haskell.  Try adding `import System.IO` at the top of your code, then put `hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering` before `putStr "test"`.  I've seen this get a lot of people (and it got me when I was first starting with Haskell).

Comment: @bheklilr it worked, thanks. Please, post this as an answer, so I could accept it.

Comment: I just pointed it back to a very similar question that already has a good accepted answer with more detail that I probably would have put here.